# vaccine or roof over your head which is more important

Tags: data.gov

when will people in Pensacola Florida receive landlord assistance the application sure is discouraging

Comment: are there any programs designed to help the individual filer who doesn't have joint custody or we just second-rate citizens

Comment: public records are so easy for the government to access why make landlords go through the redundancy the IRS has my tenants unemployment w-2s 1099 yet they must upload it properly with the PDF Adobe which in some devices is incompatible

Comment: not every landlord is Coldwell banker some of us are regular people 1523 sandcliff drive Pensacola Florida 32507 that's all you need that's all you need my tenant wants to kill me they're convinced I'm the holdup

Comment: treasury claims emergency rental assistance program showed that the number of households receiving the benefits has jumped 10%, that's underperforming but is it

Comment: basically this whole process has shown me discrimination exploitation and unfair treatment this software and these technologies Target the most vulnerable that's gross hell yeah not my problem talk to your state not my problem talk to your county

Comment: another thing most people I know have completely tuned out our president that's pretty bad 8 years ago when senator McCain was running for president there was no way he was going to make it because he was way too old